# how can I sum a column while joining three tables at once

Tags: php, mysql

I believe there is a good way to do. I searched and tried but could not find.
I want to join three tables like this (or a better way, please suggest)

```
SELECT listing.*, users.username, review.rNumber 
     FROM listing, users,review 
WHERE users.uid=listing.cuid and listing.lid=review.lID
```

But I don't want  the `review.rNumber` I want to get sum  of it like `sum(rNumber)`. Because one listing can have many reviews.. Thank you..

Here is what I want to achieve with this query

1. All the values from listing table.
2. only username from users table
3. sum of reviews from review table

The relation is

- users.uid=listing.cuid and listing.lid=review.lID 
  or
- users.uid=listing.cuid=review.sellerID

Please let me know if I need to add table.. 
Thanks :)

Comment: Not like. Did you try `SUM(review.rNumber)`? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-sum/

Comment: thank you so much,,, I tried it but may be was doing in a wrong way like review.sum(rNumber) and was getting errors

Comment: Could you please help me, how can return all the listing weather the listing has review or not. This way it only selects listing that has reviews. 
may be left join? Thank you again..

Comment: Are you sure it is the sum you want, not the count of reviews (how many reviews there are)? Also, you wrote you tried sum but got errors. Pls share what you have tried and what errors you got and then we can help you fix the code.

Comment: yes trying sum. and his @JustOnUnderMillions query works fine. But it select only the listing that has reviews but want to select the listing that don't have review... trying to use left join/outer join. but don't know how to use them with three tables.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the sum for user with  proper  group by  but for join with all the listing result you could use a dinamic join

```
SELECT listing.*, t.username, t.sum_rNumber
fFROM listing
INNER JOIN users   ON users.uid=listing.cuid
INNER JOIN review ON listing.lid=review.lID
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT  users.username as username,  sum( review.rNumber) sum_rNumber
      FROM listing
      INNER JOIN users   ON users.uid=listing.cuid
      INNER JOIN review ON listing.lid=review.lID
      GROUP BY users.username
    ) t on users.username = t.username
```

(and  is more readable the explicit join sintax)

Comment: your code didn't work. Gives unknown column errors. I then tried this way 
SELECT listing.*, t.username FROM listing INNER JOIN users ON users.uid=listing.cuid INNER JOIN review ON listing.lid=review.lID INNER JOIN ( SELECT users.username as username, sum( review.rNumber) sum_rnNumber FROM listing INNER JOIN users ON users.uid=listing.cuid INNER JOIN review ON listing.lid=review.lID GROUP BY users.username ) t on users.username = t.username

but it repeats the results

Comment: Wrong  sum_rnNumber instead of sum_rNumber  .answer  updated .. obviusly repeat the result for each row .. if you want all listing column( listing.*)  without a proper  .. group by .. you should explain the aggregation column you really need  and then  use these column for calculate the related  sum and join with main select. .. eventually  show the real column you want for aggregation or repeat all thecolumn in group by and join by id.